# How to find all reflections in Ruby array (And why mine doesn't work)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reverse

An array of all numbers below 100,000 with a factor of 19. Tested, working.

```
S= Array.new
S[0]= 19
i= 0
while S[i]+19 < 100000 do
     i+=1
     S[i] = S[i-1]+19
 end
```

The problem: Trying to find all numbers in the array that have a 'reflection' that is also in the array.

My attempt:

```
reflectionArray= Array.new
i=0

S.each do |s|
    reverse= s.to_s().reverse!
    S.each do |r|
    if (reverse == r)
        reflectionArray[i]= s
        i+=1
    end
  end
end
```

I'm expecting an array with all the mirrored factors of 19, but I get an error. 
New to Ruby today, but I could've sworn this would work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line

```
reverse= s.to_s().reverse.to_i # No need for ! and you need to convert back to a number
```

But you might want to do it this way instead

```
s = Array.new # capital variables are for class names and constantes. Btw: actually classes also are constantes
s << 19 # you don't need to use indexes at all
while s.last +19 < 100000 do
  s << s.last + 19
end
```

But you could use a range to generate your array

```
s = (19..100000).step(19)
```

And to find all the reflections in the array you could simply do

```
reverse_array = s.select {|num| num.to_s == num.to_s.reverse }
```

So at the end you can do all of that in one line :)

```
(19..100000).step(19).select {|num| num.to_s == num.to_s.reverse }
```

Comment: `TypeError: can't convert true into Integer
 from (irb):3:in 'last'
 from (irb):3
 from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in '<main>'
`

Comment: `while s.last +19 < 100000 do`

Comment: And also, the goal of the reflection is to find not just palindromes, but any number that its reverse is also in the array. Like 1187 and 7811 or something.

Comment: You can do that like this I think. `range = (19..100000).step(19); range.select {|num| num.to_s == num.to_s.reverse || ragen.include?(num.to_s.reverse.to_i) }`

Comment: `while (s.last + 19) < 100000 do`

Comment: that was a type. Should have been `range` instead